# How to make a list of variable names in VBA for Excel

Tags: arrays

I have a list of a couple of dozen variable names (type integer).  I want to assign values to them.  The values are in an array.  It seems there should be something more elegant than a couple of dozen statements like `Vrbl_1 = ValArray(1),  Vrbl_2 = ValArray(2)`, etc.

I want to keep the individual variable names because they have mnemonic value.  I tried creating an array consisting of the variable names, being careful to put them in order corresponding to the values in theValArray, but a For Loop using   namesArray(i) = ValArray(i)  doesn't work.  It puts the values into the array of names instead of putting the values into the variable name.

I think what I'm doing wrong has something to do with what are called pointers in the C language.
   Is there perhaps some way to do this using a Collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a [Dictionary](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)...

```
set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

With dictionary
  .Add "Vrbl_1", ValArray(1)
  .Add "Vrbl_2", ValArray(2)
End With
```

...and then refer to them by name.

```
dictionary.Item("Vrbl_1")
```

As you can see, it's a bit of work. Personally, I'd just stick with discrete variable names if there are only a couple dozen, or use the ValArray directly and provide generous comments.